# what's the best way to handle tag edit-warring?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

A user has just [detagged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/4460/revisions) a question I tagged. I haven't retagged: I suspect that this user would be all too happy with an edit war. It seems terribly trivial, but I've bumped into this user's snarkiness on more than one occasion previously. There didn't really seem a flag that was appropriate, other than "other", so I thought I'd solicit opinion here on the best way to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you more interested in how to handle tag edit wars in general, or just this specific one? If you want in general, what you did was best - do *not* reciprocate or rollback, and start a Meta discussion to get things settled with proper discussion.

If you want specific feedback, well, [dmckee has that for you](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-tag-edit-warring/837#837). ♪

Comment: Thanks. Well, both really I guess. So I'm a happy bunny now.

Answer (score 4):

I find myself uncertain that the tag [renewable-energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewable-energy) has a lot place on a physics site, browsing the [current list of question so tagged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewable-energy) suggests that many of them are

1. Really technology questions with little physics content. Presumable they were asked here because their authors could find no better place.
2. Often very basic.
3. Only connected to renewable energy by motivation---I mean, the asker was 
   thinking about a renewable energy application and that brought up a physics question but the question isn't about power generation as such.

In this case we seem to be looking at conditions 2 and 3. The only part of the question that is not physics 101 work is getting an estimate of the solar magnetic field strength and variation in the neighborhood of Earth's orbit. Basically this is a blue sky speculation by someone with little formal preparation; fun but not very enlightening.

I think the question has a place here, but the tag is marginal on this question.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback. I understand that the degree to which "physics 101" questions are appreciated here is the subject of some debate. I agree that many of the existing renewable-energy questions are as much about technology as about physics; perhaps once the Green Energy site gets launched and comes out of beta, we can migrate them all from here to there.